# How to change the date format if i am not able to change it?

Tags: excel, vba, date

[image]Hello,

Here is an image of my column I. I have some dates that are in the long format (example: Wednesday, June 12, 2019) and others that are in the short format (13/02/2017).

I want all the dates to be formatted as the yellow cells (in the long format) but i am not able to change the format. When i try to change the format nothing happens.

PS: If that helped i had to do some previous work with this sheet in which i went to Data --> text to column -->  and i selected date and a format dd/mm/yy for that step. But it seems that after doing that step, i am not able to coome back to any other format.

Please let me know if you have any ideas about fixing this issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you attempt to re-format a cell containing a date and the cell resists, then the cell contains a **text string** rather than a **true Excel date**.  If this is the case, you will need either a formula or VBA to make the change.

Comment: When you select a cell with the short date format, does it say date or general in that cell?

Comment: It says date in the short formatted cell

Comment: Is there a template of the VBA code to make the change @Gary'sStudent ?

Comment: A helper column could solve this. If your bad dates are in the short format shown in column B, this would work: `=Date(Right(B2,4),Mid(B2,4,2),Left(B2,2))`. Then you could paste values back over the original data.

Comment: Where did  the dates come from?  If they came from a text/csv file, then you should go back to that file, and **import** it rather than **open**ing it.  When you do that, you will be able specify the date format in the file (eg: DMY).  Excel will then properly convert the dates and you can format them however you wish in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells that resist format change and run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub DateFixer()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim v As String, d As Date

    For Each cell In Selection
        v = cell.Text
        If InStr(1, v, "/") <> 0 Then
            arr = Split(v, "/")
            d = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
            cell.Clear
            cell.Value = d
            cell.NumberFormat = "dddd,mmmm,dd,yyyy"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again @Gary's Student

Answer (score 0):

Another option to @Gary'sStudent answer is to use CDate. As Gary states, only select the cells that resist the Date format, if you select the cells that are formatted correctly, you will receive an error.

```
Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Selection
        cel.Value = CDate(cel.Value)
        cel.NumberFormat = "dddd,mmmm/dd/yyyy"
    Next cel
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it @GMalc